# Does resetting windows 8 remove other partitions

Tags: windows-8, reset

My questions looks like a duplicate but i couldn't figure out from other answers what i wanted to ask.
 I have all my data in `D` and `E` drive and windows is installed in `C drive`. If I `reset` my Windows 8.0 PC would it formats `C drive` *only* or would it *re-partition all of the hard disk* and formats  all the data including the data in `F` and `E` drive.

Comment: Reset does not repartition or format anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select `reset` option over `refresh` it deletes all your personal data but still gives you option to not format the main partition.
If you want to keep other partitions you can do so, otherwise you can format other partitions along with main partition.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jykgd.png]

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to using System Restore, then only the Windows partition will be affected.

If you are refering to using factory restore media (or partition) that your computer came with then some absolutely DO wipe everything! For example with my recovery media the entire hard drive is wiped, and restored to how it was at the factory.

You should backup your data to a different physical hard drive (or media) before attempting a factory reset just in case it's a wipe all media.

Answer (score 0):

Reset or Upgrade does not delete or format the other partitions.

Even in the case of re-installation it asks to creates a backup Windows.old folder if you're re-installing in the same old partition you had it in before.