# reinstalling windows without affecting other partition

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, reset

Followup to https://superuser.com/a/814091/129716

Does he mean that the partition structure will survive the reset but all the data on D: and E: (to use the example there) will be deleted? Or does it mean that only the data on C: will be overwritten and the data on D: and E: will survive unscathed?

Comment: Data on C: will be overwritten. D: and E: will be untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The later one is right, that is:
Data on C will be overwitten and others e.g. D & E will be untouched/unscathered